# how to escape the delimiter from the column content when export csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv, export

Im up to export the CSV file, delimiter is a "," comma but im there is a problem if column content had comma , it will break the csv out put when looking on libre office calc.

if any body can help me how to solve this

here im upto now

```
//$filename = $row['fileName'].'-ConsignmentInfo.csv';
$filename="test.csv";
$delim = ',';
$columns = array('0Product_Number', 'Product_Name', 'Alternative_Title');
echo implode($delim,$columns )."\n";           

$ptr1 = DD_Db::fetch("SELECT p.pNum,p.pName,a.varcharValue FROM ds_products p   left join productAttribute a on a.id=p.pID where a.attributeId= (select id FROM attribute where attributeName='alternateTitle') ");

 foreach ($ptr1 as $row) {
      $line = array("\"{$row['pNum']}\"","\"{$row['pName']}\"","\"{$row['varcharValue']}\"");
      echo implode($delim,$line)."\n";
 }

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Pragma: cache');
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
exit;
```

Comment: If this was Perl I'd say "Use Text::CSV" … doesn't PHP have a CSV library available? Wheel reinvention is usually not a great idea, and CVS generation is a pretty common wheel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) it takes care of escaping and producing correct csv data.

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Output:

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd
123,456,789
"""aaa""","""bbb"""
```

## Edit

You can always use a combination of [tmpfile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) to open a file that will be automatically deleted at the end of the request, write to it and then after the report is created output its content with [fread](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php). You have to use fread since tmpfile return a resource, otherwise you can use [tempnam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) + [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) but in that case you have to open the file and to cleanup after read it by yourself.

Comment: problem of this thing my client wants to download the csv after it generating

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to wrap the piece of data with a pair of `"` and use `""` to represent a double quote character in the data.

```
foo,bar,"sometimes you get data containing a "","" character","23,000"
```

Comment: please could you tell me the way to do this

Comment: A string replacement on `"` characters and then echo `"\"$foo\""`.

Comment: Im sorry Still idid nt get what you trying to tell my delimeter is , not a "

Answer (score 1):

put in quotes the value.

http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from a query using [SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)
e.g.

```
SELECT p.pNum, p.pName, a.varcharValue
FROM ds_products p   
LEFT JOIN productAttribute a ON a.id=p.pID 
WHERE a.attributeId = (select id FROM attribute where attributeName='alternateTitle')
INTO OUTFILE '/path/on/server'
```

If you want to add a header row:

```
SELECT 'A', 'B', 'C'
UNION
SELECT p.pNum, p.pName, a.varcharValue
FROM ds_products p   
LEFT JOIN productAttribute a ON a.id=p.pID 
WHERE a.attributeId = (select id FROM attribute where attributeName='alternateTitle')
INTO OUTFILE '/path/on/server'
```